# Usar mfplay em Rust pela api windows-rs

Tags: windows, rust

Alguém pode me ajudar, esse código compila normal e também não mostra nenhum erro quando executado, mais não reproduz o áudio, e um arquivo mp3

Segue o código:

```
use windows::{
    core::*,
    Win32::Media::*,
    Win32::Media::Audio::*,
    Win32::System::Com::*,
    Win32::System::Threading::*,
    Win32::Foundation::*,
    Win32::Media::MediaFoundation::*
};

const AUDIO_URL: PCWSTR = w!("./serpente.mp3");

#[implement(IMFPMediaPlayerCallback)]
struct MediaPlayerCB();

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
impl IMFPMediaPlayerCallback_Impl for MediaPlayerCB {
    fn OnMediaPlayerEvent(&self,peventheader: *const MFP_EVENT_HEADER) {
        if !peventheader.is_null() {
            let event = unsafe { &*peventheader };

            if event.hrEvent.is_err() {
                panic!("Erro {}", event.hrEvent)
            }

            match event.eEventType {
                MFP_EVENT_TYPE_MEDIAITEM_CREATED => {
                    let item: &MFP_MEDIAITEM_CREATED_EVENT = unsafe { peventheader.cast::<MFP_MEDIAITEM_CREATED_EVENT>().as_ref().unwrap()};

                    unsafe {event.pMediaPlayer.as_ref().unwrap().SetMediaItem(item.pMediaItem.as_ref().unwrap()).expect("Erro ao adicionar item") };
                },
                MFP_EVENT_TYPE_MEDIAITEM_SET => {
                    unsafe{ event.pMediaPlayer.as_ref().unwrap().Play().unwrap()}
                },
                _ => todo!()
            }
        }
    }
}

fn play_audio_mf() -> windows::core::Result<()> {
    let mut media_player: Option<IMFPMediaPlayer> = None;

    let cb: IMFPMediaPlayerCallback = MediaPlayerCB().into();

    unsafe {
        MFPCreateMediaPlayer(
            AUDIO_URL,
            TRUE,
            Default::default(),
            &cb,
            None,
            Some(&mut media_player)
        ).unwrap()
    };

    if let Some(mp) = media_player {
        unsafe { mp.SetVolume(1.0).unwrap()}

        let mut mediaitem: Option<IMFPMediaItem> = None;
        
        unsafe { mp.CreateMediaItemFromURL(AUDIO_URL, TRUE, 0, Some(&mut mediaitem)).expect("Erro nao foi possivel criar media item") };

        let mut hasaudio: BOOL = FALSE;
        let mut selected: BOOL = FALSE;

        if let Some(item) = mediaitem {
            unsafe {item.HasAudio(Some(&mut hasaudio), Some(&mut selected)).unwrap()}

            if hasaudio == FALSE {
                panic!("Nao encontrou uma midia")
            }

            if selected == TRUE {
                if hasaudio == TRUE {
                    unsafe { mp.Play().unwrap() } 
                }
            } else {
                unsafe {
                    mp.SetMediaItem(&item).unwrap();
                    mp.Play().unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> windows::core::Result<()> {
    unsafe { CoInitializeEx(None, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)? }

    match play_audio_mf() {
        Ok(it) => it,
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    };

    unsafe { CoUninitialize() }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.